# Transaction via Blockchain API using Multiple recipients

Tags: python, json, api, bitcoin, blockchain

Im trying to send bitcoins using Blockchain.info API to both adresses in 'recipes':

```
recipes ={'1Pd9gXJ8EqyGrqMKVevQWNjjF4B4dcSykf':10000,'14gVMjoCbjaGU3s9EQghVxYTAJgkmqqtHV':10000}
```

My request looks like:

```
url_multi = 'https://blockchain.info/nl/merchant/MYKEY/sendmany?password=MYPASSWORD&recipients='+recipes+'&fee=15000'

requests.get(url_multi)
```

I managed to send txs to single adresses using the examples in the [documentation](https://blockchain.info/nl/api/blockchain_wallet_api).
However, sending to multiple adresses at once requires a dict according to the PHP-example.

In Python, the following Typerror gets returned; *TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects*

How do I add multiple recipients to the request without using a dict?

Answer (score 0):

*recipes* should have been a JSON object instead. So I converted it before adding it to the URL. Works fine now.

```
x = json.dumps(recipes) 

url_multi = 'https://blockchain.info/nl/merchant/MYKEY/sendmany?password=MYPASSWORD&recipients='+x+'&fee=15000'

requests.get(url_multi)
```

I suck sometimes ;(